# создал конструктор вывода из файла. но выводит неверные числа

Tags: c++, классы, методы, перегрузка-операторов, дружественная-функция

```
product::product(std::ifstream& fin)
{
    product a;
    fin>>a.Name;
    fin>>a.Belok;
    fin>>a.Gur;
    fin>>a.Yglevod;
    fin>>a.Kkal;        
}
```

Вот этот конструктор.
записть в файл производит вот такая функция

```
friend  std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream& fout, const product& p1)
{
  fout<<p1.Name<<std::endl;
  fout<<p1.Belok <<' '<<p1.Gur<<' '<<p1.Yglevod<<' '<<p1.Kkal<<std::endl;
      return fout;
}
```

Или я не пойму как считывает данные ифстрим или где то ошибка.
http://ideone.com/L627KQ вот целый код!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
product::product(std::ifstream& fin)
{
    fin>>Name;
    fin>>Belok;
    fin>>Gur;
    fin>>Yglevod;
    fin>>Kkal;        
}
```

Вы же создавали какой-то `a`, считывали в него, и попросту выбрасывали считанное!!

Comment: я по другому вроде не могу обратиться к данным приват. в конструкторе. вроде.

Comment: Почему? Конструктор ваш, в нем вы можете обращаться к чему угодно. К унаследованным, при наследовании типа `private`, скажем - да, но эти-то поля определены в вашем классе? вот и читайте... Ну, если очень хочется - хоть это и не нужно - допишите к именам полей `this->` - типа `this->Name`...

Comment: product::product(std::ifstream& fin)
 {
  fin>>Name;
  fin>>Belok;
  fin>>Gur;
  fin>>Yglevod;
  fin>>Kkal;  
 }

Comment: вы имеете ввиду вот так сделать?

Comment: Ну я же именно это в ответе и написал :)

Comment: все, равно какие то левые числа вызывает. то же самое. может потому что я пробелы делал во время добавления в файл(офстрим)?

Comment: См. тут - http://ideone.com/Tk7PKm - упрощенный пример. Ввод из консоли, вывод туда же. У вас имя точно из одного слова? :)

Comment: точно из одного)

Comment: вот не хочет оно имя загружатьт вообще, ачисловые данные какие то не те цифры. 
http://s019.radikal.ru/i633/1612/c4/ac11ab746865.jpg
вот что выводит.

Comment: Блин... Ладно, сложите все - включая файл с данными - куда-то на файлообменник и киньте ссылку. Ну что я мгу сказать, не имея телепатических способностей?

Comment: http://dropmefiles.com/Ftl4m
вот

Comment: Вы читаете информацию из product.txt?

Comment: да, из продукт тхт

Comment: Но в нем же записана не только информация, но и имена полей... Тогда читать надо совсем по другому, выбрасывая все до двоеточия. То, что написал я, было рассчитано на совсем другой форма - когда просто в одной строке - имя, второй - число, третей и так далее - тоже... во такой: `awa
15
12
15
228` (все может быть и в одной строке).

Comment: до этого были только данные и пробелы, все равно считывало так

Comment: Посмотрел. Да вы хоть файл откройте для начала... Откуда вы читаете? fin ведь не открыт!

Comment: это через фин.опен?
я думал фоут.опен и для того и для того сработает

Comment: точно, в этом ошибка и была, что не открывал файл. спасибо. еще три дня думал бы, если бы сам делал

Comment: Ну, с fout и fin все равно как по звонку гостей открыть дверь на балкон и ждать, что они войдут через входную... :)